# JQuery .load event not fired on anchor link click event

Tags: jquery

I have a webpage with search form fields and on click of submit button,
I do an Ajax call and fill a div with results using Ajax.BeginForm

The results have paging links to handle paging.

The problem is after the Ajax call I have this Jquery code that should fire when one of the paging links is clicked. But they do not fire.

Is this because the div is filled using Ajax call?

I tested that code using the click of the submit button and it fires ok. Just the paging links don't fire.

```
$('.pagerlinks a').click(function () {
    $('#resultsdiv').load('Search/Advanced', { Keywords=keywords, etc });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of doing it is by rebinding in a callback function, called as `$.load`'s second parameter:

```
function initPagerlinks()
{
     $('.pagerlinks a').click(function() {
           $('#resultsdiv').load('Search/Advanced', {Keywords=keywords, etc }, initPagerlinks); 
     });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    initPagerlinks();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use the live binding function in jquery to be able to bind to all specified elements at any time of creation:

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live

Also does your code fire on DOM ready event? as in:

```
$(function () {
 $('.pagerlinks a').click(function() {
       $('#resultsdiv').load('Search/Advanced', {Keywords=keywords, etc }); 
});

});
```

Comment: Yes I do have the ready event coded. I will try this live binding. But should what I have done worked????

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:
1. Add to load function callback that setups events on loaded content.
2. Use live events:

`$("p").live("click", function(){
          $(this).after("Another paragraph!");
    });`

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live